in c: my special free function refuses to work
A function that returns a 2D list of pointers to every possible knight movements on a grid.
Everything works except my spacial free function that crashes in random locations:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB2CC5C55C (ucrtbased.dll) in project q1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

It's trying to free an unlawful location, but the location is random and I don't know what caused it:
typedef char chessPos[2];
typedef struct _chessPosArray {
    unsigned int size;
    chessPos *positions;
} chessPosArray;

bool isPosInBoard(chessPos pos);
chessPosArray ***validKnightMoves();
chessPos *KnightMoveFromLocation(int row, int col, unsigned int *lenght);
void printKnightMovesInCur(chessPosArray ***possArr, int row, int col);
void freeCPA(chessPosArray ***possArr);
bool isEmpthy(const void *node);

chessPosArray ***validKnightMoves() {
    chessPosArray ***finle = (chessPosArray ***)malloc(sizeof(chessPosArray **) * B_SIZE);
    if (isEmpthy(finle)) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed for final\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < B_SIZE; i++) {
        finle[i] = (chessPosArray **)malloc(sizeof(chessPosArray *) * B_SIZE);
        if (isEmpthy(finle[i])) {
            printf("Memory allocation failed for final[%d]\n", i);
            exit(1);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < B_SIZE; j++) {
            finle[i][j] = (chessPosArray *)malloc(sizeof(chessPosArray));
            if (isEmpthy(finle[i][j])) {
                printf("Memory allocation failed for final[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
                exit(1);
            }
            finle[i][j]->positions = KnightMoveFromLocation(i, j, &finle[i][j]->size);
        }
    }
    return finle;
}

chessPos *KnightMoveFromLocation(int row, int col, unsigned int *lenght) {
    int columns[8] = { 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };
    int Rows[8] = { -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2 };
    chessPos posHold;
    posHold[0] = 'A' + row;
    posHold[1] = '1' + col;
    int newlenght = 0;
    chessPos *rePos = (chessPos *)malloc(sizeof(chessPos) * 8);
    if (isEmpthy(rePos)) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed for rePos\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    chessPos *pointer = rePos;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        chessPos posChecker = { posHold[0] + Rows[i], posHold[1] = posHold[1] + columns[i] };
        if (isPosInBoard(posChecker)) {
            (*pointer)[0] = posChecker[0];
            (*pointer)[1] = posChecker[1];
            pointer++;
            newlenght++;
        }
    } 
    realloc(rePos, sizeof(chessPos) * newlenght);
    *lenght = newlenght;
    return rePos;
}

bool isPosInBoard(chessPos pos) {
    int row = pos[0] - 'A';
    int col = pos[1] - '1';
    if (row < 0 || row >= B_SIZE || col < 0 || col >= B_SIZE) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void freeCPA(chessPosArray ***possArr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < B_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B_SIZE; j++) {
            // vvv this is where the program crashes vvv
            free(possArr[i][j]->positions);
            free(possArr[i][j]);
        }
        free(possArr[i]);
    }
    free(possArr);
}

bool isEmpthy(const void *node) {
    if (node == NULL)
        return true;
    return false;
}

I marked the problematic line. Tried to check if it's null before or turn it to null next. It passes through the hole grid so the i can't be out of bounds.
Debugging locations (every location).
Printing them printing where its fails, checking nulls, making its null.

What is spcail? I don't see that in the code.

Aside: don't cast malloc

realloc() returns a new pointer, it doesn't (can't) modify rePos in place. You need to assign that to a variable and return that. You should also check whether it was successful.

...also, if the reallocated memory block is in a different position, the original pointer is now invalid, and you threw away the new pointer.

@WeatherVane hay thanks but the moment i free the prevoius pointer(as i should) the pogream collaps on its self

Exactly: you free a pointer which is no longer valid, and you don't know what its replacement pointer is. There is no free() action you can take.

Beware becoming a three star programmer.

There's probably very little reason for all this dynamic allocation. The chessboard size is known at compile time, so you can just declare chessPosArray finle[B_SIZE][B_SIZE]. The only thing that needs to be allocated dynamically is positions, since it can grow.

@Barmar: I agree, and since positions is at most 8 entries of 2 bytes each, allocating that is overkill too.

@chqrlie I didn't get that deep into the code to realize there was a limit on the reallocs.

@Chris i didnt know my uni teacher wanted us to become coders super stars. that *** qauntion all ways confused me . which is wierdier is me discovering its was actully kinda a **** because the posarray also has a pointer. shit confsued me .

how do i mark that my qauntion was all ready answerd?


There are multiple problems. Mainly:

realloc(rePos, sizeof(chessPos) * newlenght) may return a pointer different from rePos even if the reallocated size is smaller than the current size.  In this case, using rePos after the call to realloc has undefined behavior, which may explain the crash when passing it to free. The return value should be stored into rePos, but only if non NULL.
Furthermore, you should also check for allocation failure and keep the original pointer in this case.  Reallocating the block seems overkill for your purpose, just remove this line.
isEmpthy should be spelled isEmpty or renamed isNull and simplified as
bool isNull(const void *node) { return node == NULL; }

Using a function for this is not idiomatic in C, just write:
    if (!rePos) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed for rePos\n");
        exit(1);
    }


the initializer in chessPos posChecker = { posHold[0] + Rows[i], posHold[1] = posHold[1] + columns[i] }; is incorrect, you should not update posHold[i].  Use this instead:
chessPos posChecker = { posHold[0] + Rows[i], posHold[1] + columns[i] };



Note that there is no need for so many indirections, and using more than 2 is good sign that the data structure is too complicated: you should instead define a single structure with a 2D array of chessPosArray structures, allocated in a single call and populated with two simple nested loops:
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define B_SIZE  8

typedef char chessPos[2];

typedef struct chessPosArray {
    unsigned int size;
    chessPos positions[8]; // up to 8 possible destinations
} chessPosArray;

typedef struct chessKnightMoves {
    chessPosArray finle[B_SIZE][B_SIZE];
};

bool isPosInBoard(chessPos pos);
chessKnightMoves *validKnightMoves(void);
unsigned int knightMoveFromLocation(chessPos *rePos, int row, int col);
void printKnightMovesInCur(chessKnightMoves *kp, int row, int col);
void freeCPA(chessKnightMoves *kp);

chessKnightMoves *validKnightMoves(void) {
    // calloc initializes the memory block to all bits 0.
    chessKnightMoves *kp = calloc(1, sizeof(*kp));
    if (!kp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed for knithMoves\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < B_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B_SIZE; j++) {
            kp->finle[i][j].size = KnightMoveFromLocation(finle[i][j].positions, i, j);
        }
    }
    return kp;
}

unsigned int knightMoveFromLocation(chessPos *rePos, int row, int col) {
    static int const cols[8] = { 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };
    static int const rows[8] = { -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2 };
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        chessPos posChecker = { 'A' + row + rows[i], '1' + col + cols[i] };
        if (isPosInBoard(posChecker)) {
            rePos[count] = posChecker;
            count++;
        }
    } 
    return count;
}

bool isPosInBoard(chessPos pos) {
    int row = pos[0] - 'A';
    int col = pos[1] - '1';
    return (row >= 0 && row < B_SIZE && col >= 0 && col < B_SIZE);
}

void freeCPA(chessKnightMoves *kp) {
    free(kp);
}


so i can see what you did here and i very much apprieart it . i all ready fixed al of my other bugs yestrady so my func works. sadly i cant change how its builds . they directly told us which typ deff to use and how the first func should be named(the *** dots hell).  sadly i was stuck whit this kind of writng whit pointer in pointers in pointers

That's OK... What matters is for you do understand the concept behind pointers. You seem to have gotten it, so you will learn the rest of the C language easily and also get a good sense of CPU inner workings. Enjoy the journey :)

@yuvalgabay: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.
